# Format Request Payload in a loop

Tags: python, json, request, format

I am trying to loop on an API request by doing the same request 12 times:

this is the payload part of the request, this works:

```
    payload="{\n\t\"filter\": {\n        \"year\":2020,\n        \"month\":10,\n\t\t\"customer_id\":52\n\t},\n    \"sort\":{\"_id.date\":1}\n}"
```

My goal is to format the payload string by adding the looped variable "mes" after month. As far as I understand I tried to use:

```
for mes in range(0,12):
      payload="{\n\t\"filter\": {\n        \"year\":2020,\n        \"month\": 
     {mes},\n\t\t\"customer_id\":52\n\t},\n    \"sort\":{\"_id.date\":1}\n}".format(mes=mes)
```

But is not working, how can I format it so I can loop through the Payload?
What could be a solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `.format()` you cannot have `{}` in the str as they will be recognized as the place to put the str in `.format()`. You need to double each one of them where you do not intend to use formatted str:

```
for mes in range(0,12):
      payload="{{\n\t\"filter\": {{\n        \"year\":2020,\n        \"month\"{mes},\n\t\t\"customer_id\":52\n\t}},\n    \"sort\":{{\"_id.date\":1}}\n}}".format(mes=mes)
```

In short, `'{a} {something else}'.format(a=1)` does not work but `'{a} {{something else}}'.format(a=1)` works and gets printed as `'1 {something else}'`